# what is prevObject and context in pushstack in jquery ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand how the pushstack function works and I also understand how to use it for my plugins (I guess that's what its most used for , just for internal use and for end() to function properly and other similar methods) .

now below is the jquery source of pushstack , have a look :

```
pushStack: function( elems ) {
    // Build a new jQuery matched element set
    var ret = jQuery.merge( this.constructor(), elems );
    // Add the old object onto the stack (as a reference)
    ret.prevObject = this;
    ret.context = this.context;
    // Return the newly-formed element set
    return ret;
},
```

theres a lot going on in that function really and I kind of get most part of it , but I have a small problem , understanding the below lines of code :-

```
ret.prevObject = this;
ret.context = this.context;
```

what is `prevObject` and `context` ? can somebody give me a clue , it definitely does't seem to be a javascript thing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `prevObject` is used to allow flexibility for the jquery selectors chaining syntax.

> Most of jQuery's DOM traversal methods operate on a jQuery object instance and produce a new one, matching a different set of DOM elements. When this happens, it is as if the new set of elements is pushed onto a stack that is maintained inside the object. Each successive filtering method pushes a new element set onto the stack

Everytime you make a new filter a new jquery instance is constructed matching your selector and the previous one is stored in it to allow the `.end()` and the `addBack()` functions to work (most of the DOM transversal functions use pushStack internally). If this property were not used every selector will forget about the previous one and it will not behave like a stack. Think *parent* instead of *prevObject* and it will make it easier to understand.

The `context` property is deprecated in jQuery 1.10 and only used for supporting `live()` method but it must be added because the returning object is constructed merging an empty jQuery constructor as first parameter and a set of elements as the second.

```
var ret = jQuery.merge( this.constructor(), elems );
```

Because `.merge` returns the first array modified it's context property might not have the correct value so is overwritten with the correct one `this.context`

Check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devconcept/ekna0LrL/3/) and open the console. You will see that the first value of prevObject is the document as we are making a new selector and then is the `ul` element since we filter using find. Moreover you can go to the last filter and lookup the whole chain of selectors up to the document again.

I recommend you to use the JQuery API instead of this property as reference in production but this will allow you for example to know the result of all the selectors that have been applied to obtain a given set of DOM elements.